Is there a scenario where `foo in list(bar)` cannot be replaced by `foo in bar`?
I'm digging into a codebase containing thousands of occurrences of foo in list(bar), e.g.:

as a boolean expression:
if foo in list(bar) or ...:
   ...


in a for loop:
for foo in list(bar):
    ...


in a generator expression:
",".join(str(foo) for foo in list(bar))



Is there a scenario (like a given version of Python, a known behavior with a type checker, etc.) where foo in list(bar) is not just a memory-expensive version of foo in bar? What am I missing here?

Kind of depends on what bar actually is. The behavior of in for objects of a class is defined by how it overrides __contains__. It's possible that bar.__contains__(foo) is not equivalent to list(bar).__contains__(foo)

Isn't that the whole point of the question? If you guys are going to say, "it depends," then do you have a specific scenario in mind?

Did you try to figure out or ask for the reasons in the code you have?

I'm curious about that. The answers show some reasons for calling list there, but I think it's still a rare need, so thousands of occurrences is still surprising.

I've sometimes done/seen that when bar got modified in the loop, e.g.:
bar = {1, 2, 3}
for foo in list(bar):
    bar.add(foo + 1)

With your replacement, that raises RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration.
Attempt This Online!
An example from Python's standard library
    for k in list(_config_vars):
        if k.startswith(_INITPRE):
            del _config_vars[k]

Dozens more (many done for the above reason, though not all).

Isn't this more of a side effect of using pop, whereas the question was asking about the initial iteration?

@OneCricketeer Not sure what you mean with being about the initial iteration. I think they're asking whether it's safe to remove the list calls. And this is a technique I've actually used/seen and I think it might actually be what they have in their code. And it's not safe to remove it there.

this is probably the most probable example where you would see a valid use-case for for x in list(something)

Here it makes a difference:
bar = iter('bar')
foo = 'b'
if foo in list(bar):
    print(*bar)

That prints an empty line. With your replacement, it prints a r instead.
Attempt This Online!

So, anyone could create a type that works this way:
>>> class Crazy:
...     def __iter__(self):
...         yield from range(10)
...
>>> 3 in Crazy()
True
>>> class Crazy:
...     def __iter__(self): yield from range(10)
...     def __contains__(self, item): raise TypeError("sorry, cant do that")
...
>>> 3 in Crazy()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __contains__
TypeError: sorry, cant do that
>>> 3 in list(Crazy())
True
>>>

Most of the built-in types are "well behaved". However, one important exception is probably str and other similar types (bytes, bytearray):
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'
True
>>> 'foo' in list('foobar')
False

Also, for at least one popular library,numpy, this isn't the case:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> 6 in arr
True
>>> 6 in list(arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>


With their situation in mind, I think the NumPy example has it backwards. Since 6 in list(arr) doesn't work, that's probably not a case they have. It doesn't show that removing list() might be problematic, it shows that adding it might be problematic. (Another example of that is 3 in list(itertools.count())... I had decided against posting that because of the backwardness.)

@nocomment that's a good point, but I just wanted to emphasize that third-party libraries are under no obligation to make these consistent

If foo and bar are both strings, membership tests behave differently. <str> in <str> checks substrings while <str> in list(<str>) checks characters.
>>> foo = 'ab'
>>> bar = 'abc'
>>> foo in bar  # Substring
True
>>> foo in list(bar)  # Element (character)
False


Regarding looping, don't let the syntax fool you, it's not the same as the boolean expression. Looping uses the iterable protocol (such as __iter__), while the boolean expression uses the membership testing protocol (such as __contains__, or it falls back to the iterable protocol)

When bar is a generator, bar and list(bar) may have other differences. Here is one example:
def abc():
    yield 'a'
    yield 'b'
    yield 'c'
    raise Exception('Incorrect data')

foo = 'a'

if foo in abc():
    print('without list()')     # <-- This is printed (`raise` is not reached)

if foo in list(abc()):          # <-- This raises an exception
    print('with list()')        # <-- So this is never reached

In the first case, if foo in abc() does not exhaust the generator. Due to lazy evaluation, once 'a' is yielded, the generator will not yield any more items.
In the second case, if foo in list(abc()) exhausts the generator, which raises an exception. So 'with list()' is never printed.

I think the exception makes this a suboptimal example, since that means they likely don't have such a case in their code.

(In other words: same reasoning as I commented under juanpa's answer)
